# Jenkins Pipeline gcloud problems in docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, google-authentication, google-container-registry

I'm trying to set up jenkins pipeline according to
[this](https://tech.winton.com/2017/04/continuous-deployment-of-containerised-microservic/) article but instead use google container registry to push the docker images to.

The Problem: The part which fails me is this jenkinsfile stage block

```
stage ('Push Docker Image To Container Registry') {
  docker.image('google/cloud-sdk:alpine').inside {
      sh "echo ${env.GOOGLE_AUTH} > gcp-key.json"
      sh 'gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ./service-account-creds.json'
  }
}
```

The Error:

```
Please verify that you have permissions to write to the parent directory.)

ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) Could not create directory [/.config/gcloud]: Permission denied.
```

I can't run any command to do with gcloud as the error above is what i get all the time.

I tried create the "/.config" directory manually logged into the aws instance and open up the permission of the folder to everyone but that didn't help either.

I also can't find anywhere how to properly setup google cloud for jenkins pipeline using docker.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hello, so that I understand your setup better, can I ask, are you running Jenkins on a Compute Engine instance? If so, if you SSH into the machine and run gcloud commands manually, does this generate the same error?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am running jenkins on aws ec2 instance and i don't have gcloud sdk installed on the instance itself, but i am trying to use the docker image for google cloud sdk to allow me to execute this section of the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's trying to write data directly into your root file system directory. 
The .config directory for gcloud would normally be in the following locations for username and/or root user:

```
/home/yourusername/.config/gcloud
/root/.config/gcloud
```

It looks like, for some reason, jenkins thinks the parent directory should be in /.

I would try checking where your cloud sdk config directories are on the machine you are running this on (and for the user the scripts runs as):

```
$ sudo find / -iname "gcloud"
```

And look for location similars to those printed above.

Could it be that the Cloud SDK is installed in a none standard location on the machine?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I don't have gcloud installed on the ec2 instance itself as i am pulling down a docker image for google cloud sdk and trying to get it to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that when Jenkins runs a docker container, it passes the user ID of the user on the host machine, so for example:

```
docker run -t -d -u 501:501 \
  -w /home/worker/workspace/vcg-gcp-image-build \
  -v /home/worker/workspace/vcg-gcp-image-build:/home/worker/workspace/vcg-gcp-image-build:rw,z \
  -v /home/worker/workspace/vcg-gcp-image-build@tmp:/home/worker/workspace/vcg-gcp-image-build@tmp:rw,z \
  -e CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/tmp/.config/gcloud \
  -e ******** \
  ...
```

That user (in this case `501`) probably doesn't exist on the docker container so it doesn't really have a home directory or anything like that, but it's running as a normal user and not `root` so it won't have permission to write to `/` (or specifically `/.config/gcloud`).  I would think that the user WOULD have permission to `/home/worker/...`; however, that didn't seem to be the case for me.

I worked around the issue by setting `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/tmp/.config/gcloud'` as an environment variable for the pipeline and then passing `args "-e CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=${CLOUDSDK_CONFIG}"` to tell `gcloud` to use a different directory for `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG`.

Our pipeline looks something like this:

```
def DOCKER_IMAGE  = 'google/cloud-sdk'
def DOCKER_TAG    = '467.0.0'
def DOCKER_DIGEST = 'sha256:f9c069499365d5d8a227d40e7c61af7380a6f24444f8d38b828fa812518050b4'

...

pipeline {
  agent { label 'foo-bar' }

  environment {
    ...

    CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/tmp/.config/gcloud' # Needs to be somewhere that the docker user has write access to, so we used /tmp
    
    ...
  }

  stages {
  
    ...

    stage('Upload the artifact to Google Cloud Storage') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image "${DOCKER_IMAGE}:${DOCKER_TAG}@${DOCKER_DIGEST}"
          args "-e CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=${CLOUDSDK_CONFIG}"
          reuseNode true
        }
      }

      steps {
        script {
          withCredentials([
            file(
              credentialsId: "${CREDENTIALS_ID}",
              variable: 'GCP_KEY'
            )
          ]) {
            sh("""
              mkdir -p ${CLOUDSDK_CONFIG}

              gcloud auth activate-service-account ${SERVICE_ACCOUNT} \
                --key-file=${GCP_KEY} \
                --project=${PROJECT}

              if gcloud storage ls gs://${BUCKET}/${FILE_NAME} > /dev/null
              then
                echo "The artifact already exists: gs://${BUCKET}/${FILE_NAME}"
              else
                echo "The artifact does not exist yet, uploading..."

                gcloud storage cp \
                  /home/worker/workspace/vcg-gcp-image-build/artifacts/${FILE_NAME} \
                  gs://${BUCKET}
              fi
            """)
          }   // end - withCredentials
        }     // end - script
      }       // end - steps
    }         // end - stage - Upload the image to Google Cloud Storage

    stage('Import Google Compute Image') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image "${DOCKER_IMAGE}:${DOCKER_TAG}@${DOCKER_DIGEST}"
          args "-e CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=${CLOUDSDK_CONFIG}"
          reuseNode true
        }
      }

      steps {
        script {
          withCredentials([
            file(
              credentialsId: "${CREDENTIALS_ID}",
              variable: 'GCP_KEY'
            )
          ]) {
            sh("""
              mkdir -p ${CLOUDSDK_CONFIG}

              gcloud auth activate-service-account ${SERVICE_ACCOUNT} \
                --key-file=${GCP_KEY} \
                --project=${PROJECT}

              gcloud compute images import ${IMAGE_NAME} \
                --source-file="gs://${BUCKET}/${FILE_NAME}" \
                --compute-service-account="${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}" \
                --cloudbuild-service-account="${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}" \
                --log-location="gs://${BUCKET}/" \
                --network="${NETWORK}" \
                --subnet="${SUBNET}" \
                --zone="${ZONE}" --no-address --quiet --os=${OS}
            """)
          }   // end - withCredentials
        }     // end - script
      }       // end - steps
    }         // end - stage - Upload the image to Google Cloud Storage

  }           // end - stages
}             // end - pipeline
```

Looks like I'm a little over 6 years late to help you, but hopefully this helps someone else in the future.