# Unable to use gcloud in a jenkins docker-agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gcloud

I'm trying to run a jenkins pipeline with a docker agent (google/cloud-sdk:alpine) to deploy my code to App Engine. Unfortunately, it seams I have no permission to to that although I'm root in the docker.

The issue tends to be the same as in this post : [Jenkins Pipeline gcloud problems in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290088/jenkins-pipeline-gcloud-problems-in-docker)
But there is no right answer to this issue.

When I launch theses command by hand, everything works.

My Jenkinsfile is :

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { 
            image 'registry.hub.docker.com/google/cloud-sdk:alpine' 
            args '-v $HOME:/home -w /home'    
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'bnc-hub', variable: 'SECRET_JSON')]) {
                    sh '''
                    set +x
                    gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $SECRET_JSON
                    gcloud config set project bnc-hub
                    gcloud app deploy app.yaml
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The return in Jenkins is :

```
[workspace] Running shell script
+ set +x
WARNING: Could not setup log file in /.config/gcloud/logs, (Error: Could not create directory [/.config/gcloud/logs/2018.12.28]: Permission denied.
Please verify that you have permissions to write to the parent directory.)
script returned exit code 1
```

Comment: I do not use Jenkins, but from the error message gcloud is trying to write to /.config. This requires root permission and means that gcloud is not setup for the user (service) that Jenkins is running under.

Comment: The thing is I use the official  docker image of the cloud sdk : https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/
When I launch my commands by hand it works, but not from Jenkins.
In both situations the user is root.

Comment: Compare the environment variables in both situations.

Comment: I have my answer.

Jenkins didn't flush the last line return by gcloud which was : Do you want to continue (Y/n)? .

So I was in interactive mode. I just added a --quiet to my request and everything work fine right now !

Thank you for your support !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default HOME=/

Add
HOME=$WORKSPACE
before
gcloud auth  activate-service-account  --key-file=${GCP_SA}

worked for me